# How do I disable multipath route caching in linux?

Tags: cache, iproute2

It seems that there used to be a config option to disable multipath ip route caching in linux, but has since been removed?

Is there any workaround for this, or method of disabling this behavior?

Comment: Why would you want to?

Comment: @Zoredache: more than likely to load balancing via multipath routing - caching routes in such a case totally messes up the purpose.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that due to [bugs and lack of ownership](http://lists.openwall.net/netdev/2007/03/12/76), multipath IP route caching was [removed from the Linux kernel](http://lwn.net/Articles/241465/) - that being the case, I'd recommend using a Linux with kernel 2.6.23 or greater.